# Martingales in Ruin Theory - Crámer-Loundberg model

Tags: probability, martingales, actuarial-science

In the classic Crámer-Lundberg Model 
$$U_t=u + ct - S_t$$
Defining 
$$g(r)=\lambda (M_U (r) - 1) - cr$$
where $M_U$ is the moment generating function of $U$ and the adjustment coefficient R is going to be constructed as $g(R)=0$

We kow that $E[e^{-r(U_t - U_s)}]=e^{(t-s)g(r)}$ for $s<t$

And to show that $E(e^{-rU_t - g(r)t})=e^{-rU_s - g(r)s}$ (is a martingale) for $s<t$.

I found in some probability theory lectures online:
\begin{align}
E(e^{-rU_t - g(r)t}|F_s)&= E(e^{-r(U_t - U_s)})e^{-rU_s - (\lambda(M_U (r) - 1)-cr)t}\\ 
&= E(e^{-r(U_t - U_s)})e^{-rU_s - \lambda(M_U (r) - 1)-crs}\\
&=e^{-rU_s - g(r)s}
\end{align}

Yet I can't see how we do these steps, and the first one doesn't make sense to me at all.

Doing:
\begin{align}
E(e^{-rU_t - g(r)t}|F_s)&=E(e^{-r(U_t - U_s) - rU_s - g(r)t}|F_s)\\
&= e^{(t-s)g(r)} e^{rU_s} E(e^{-g(r)t}|F_s)
\end{align}

I think I get closer to the answer, but I can't show the first step (that they are independent so I can do the product of expectations) and if $E(e^{-g(r)t}|F_s)$ is martingale (which I also can't prove), I would get $E(e^{-g(r)t}|F_s)=e^{-g(r)s}$ and a wrong answer. What am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

first of all, when you say that $M_U$ is the moment generating function of $U$, you are not being precise! $U$ is a stochastic process.
 What you probably mean is that **$M_U$ is the moment generation function of $U_1$.** Then we also have that
\begin{align}\tag{1} \label{1}
\mathbb{E}\bigl[ \exp(-r\cdot U_t)\bigr] = \exp(g(r) \cdot t), \quad \text{for all} \ t \geq 0.
\end{align}

Second,  the function $t \mapsto e^{-g(r)t}$ does not involve any random variables, hence it is a deterministic function. In particular we have that
$$
\mathbb{E}\bigl[ e^{-g(r)t} \mid \mathcal{F}_s \bigr] = 
\mathbb{E}\bigl[ e^{-g(r)t}  \bigr] = e^{-g(r)t}.
$$ 
Also,  $t \mapsto e^{-g(r)t}$
is **not a martingale** because it is a determinisitic function in $t$ which is not constant.

---

**Edit: new part**

## Properties of the stochastic process $U$

From the definition of $U$ we see that the only random element in it is the process $S$ which is a compound Poisson process. This means that there exists a Poisson process $N$ and an i.i.d. sequence $X$ such that
$$
S_t= \sum_{i=1}^{N_t}X_i.
$$
Per definition, $N$ has independent and stationary increments. It is then an easy exercise to show that $S$ inherits these properties from $N$, meaning that $S$ also has  independent and stationary increments. 
It then follows that $U$ also has independent and stationary increments.

---

## Martingale part

From here on we use the stationary and independent increments of the Compound Poisson process: these properties are handed on to the process $U$, hence we have that
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\bigl[ \exp(-r\cdot U_t)\mid \mathcal{F}_s \bigr] = \mathbb{E}\Bigl[ \exp\bigl(-r\cdot (U_t-U_s)\bigr) \cdot \exp(-r\cdot U_s)\mid \mathcal{F}_s \Bigr].
\end{align} 
Now $\exp(-r\cdot U_s)$ is $\mathcal F_s$ measurable hence we can take it out of the conditional expectation. Furthermore, $U_t-U_s$ is independent from $\mathcal{F}_s$, therefore the conditional expectation is equal to the *"normal"* expectation: we arrive at
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\Bigl[ \exp\bigl(-r\cdot (U_t-U_s)\bigr) \cdot \exp(-r\cdot U_s)\mid \mathcal{F}_s \Bigr] = \mathbb{E}\Bigl[ \exp\bigl(-r\cdot (U_t-U_s)\bigr) \Bigr] \cdot\exp(-r\cdot U_s).
\end{align} 
Next we will use that $U_t-U_s$ has the same distribution as $U_{t-s}$. If two random variables have the same distribution they also have the same expectation, hence we get:
\begin{align}
 \mathbb{E}&\Bigl[ \exp\bigl(-r (U_t-U_s)\bigr) \Bigr] \exp(-r U_s)= \mathbb{E}\Bigl[ \exp\bigl(-r\cdot U_{t-s}\bigr) \Bigr] \exp(-r U_s) \\[6pt] &\stackrel{(\ref{1})}{=}\exp\bigl(g(r) \cdot (t-s)\bigr) \exp(-r U_s).
\end{align} 
To sum up, we have shown that
\begin{align} \tag{2} \label{2}
\mathbb{E}\bigl[ \exp(-r U_t)\mid \mathcal{F}_s \bigr]=\exp\bigl(g(r) \cdot (t-s)\bigr) \exp(-r U_s).
\end{align}

From here it is easy to show the martingale property: 
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}&\bigl[ \exp\bigl(-r U_t -tg(r)\bigr)\mid \mathcal{F}_s \bigr] = \mathbb{E}\bigl[ \exp(-r U_t)\mid \mathcal{F}_s \bigr]\exp\bigl(- tg(r)\bigr)\\[6pt] 
& \stackrel{(\ref{2})}{=} \exp\bigl(g(r) \cdot (t-s)\bigr) \exp(-r U_s)\exp\bigl(- tg(r)\bigr) \\[6pt]& = \exp\bigl(-r U_s -sg(r)\bigr).
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you, your answer was very clear, except some points:
-Why does $U_t - U_s$ has the same distribution as $U_{t-s}$?
I get the expressions:
$U_t - U_s= c(t-s) - \sum_{i=N_s}^{n=N_t}$
but $U_{t-s}= u+c(t-s) - \sum_{i=0}^{n=N_{t-s}}$

-Why is $U_t - U_s$ independent from $F_s$?
$U_S$ in $F_s$-mensurable, but isn't $F_s \subset F_t$ and so dependent?

Comment: I edited the answer, and tried to answer your questions. You need to lookup the definition of a Poisson process